# Mandelstam variables for 2 to 3 particle scattering

Tags: quantum-field-theory, invariants

I'm trying to work out the mandelstam variables for 2 particles scattering to produce 3 particles. Also each particle is massless.

I think there must be 5 because all possible scalar products of the incoming and outgoing momentum must be expressible in terms of the mandelstam variables, and there are 6 possible scalar products. But only 5 are linearly independent. Thus there are 5 Mandelstam variables.

But I don't know how to actually calculate them? Are they equal to the 5 linearly independent scalar products? Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: There is (must be) a degree of freedom in this, so start by stealing the two standard ones that have clear physics interpretations (total 4-momentum $s$ and 4-mometum transfer $t$ (though the usual definition assumes there is a particle in the final state that can be associated with a particle in the initial state... ), then you have the smaller problem of finding three more combination that are orthogonal to the one you already have (and mutually orthogonal, of course).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are potentially two different questions: how many different non trivial mandelstam variables and how many independent mandelstam variables there are. The claim is that there are 10 different mandelstam variables for 5 particle process, and there are 5 independent mandelstam variables.

First, all possible mandelstam variables can be written as $s_{i_1\dots i_l}=-(p_{i_1}+\dots+p_{i_l})^2$ with $l\leq5$.But due to the momentum conservation, $\sum_{i=1}^5p_i=0$, they are not all distinct. More specifically, we see $l=1,4$ or $5$ give trivial ones. $l=2$ gives the same variables as $l=3$ because of momentum conservation.Thus we may just consider the case with $l=2$, and it gives ${5 \choose 2}=10$ different non-trivial mandelstam variables, and $s_{ij}=-2p_ip_j$.

Now for linearly independent ones, we see that the following relations hold for all $i$:

$$\sum_{j\neq i}s_{ij}=0,$$
as we can directly compute using the momentum conservation: 
$$\sum_{j\neq i}s_{ij}=-2p_i\sum_{j\neq i}p_j=2p_i^2=0.$$

Thus we have at most 5 linearly independent mandelstam variables. It takes a little bit more to show the other direction to conclude that for example, $s_{12},s_{13},s_{14},s_{23},s_{24}$ is a set of generators.

Comment: I am not sure how you deal with sign, for example when you say $\sum p_i=0$